# How to find on which column last/recent filter was applied in aggrid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In our project we use serverSideDataSource, so the getRows method gets called with request params having below request model,

```
{
    "startRow": 0,
    "endRow": 50,
    "rowGroupCols": [],
    "valueCols": [],
    "pivotCols": [],
    "pivotMode": false,
    "groupKeys": [],
    "filterModel": {
        "columnA": {
            "filterType": "number",
            "type": "equals",
            "filter": 123
        },
        "columnB": {
            "filterType": "number",
            "type": "equals",
            "filter": 676
        }
    },
    "sortModel": []
}
```

But recent filter was applied on columnB, but there is just no way to tell that was the recent filter applied.Please help !!

Comment: Have you tried using filter model ? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-api/

Comment: @AkshAyAgrawal i saw filter-api as well but it did not tell on which column recent filter was applied on